# Using Java if we run two JVM's at the same time what are the limitations I must keep in mind?

Tags: java, jvm

Is it possible to spawn off two separate Java programs , say program `Apples.java` and `Grapes.java` , and each one of these runs in its own separate JVM on the machine ?

My motivation for this  is that I want to have a Monitor class, which will be checking the log-files that are output by another class (call it the `UnderSurveillance` class) .  And once that child class is forcibly shutdown, then the Monitor class will act on this (it will call a batch file via ProcessBuilder that will spawn off another `UnderSurveillance`  class ).

To summarize ,  if we call `CTRL+C` from command-line on `UnderSurveillance`  , then it should be respawned again.  And when it is respawned it will resume state. For example, if this was a knockknock joke app, then it would restart in the logical position where we left off before (so if we had 10 knock-knock jokes, and we forcibly shutdown before completing KK-joke #5, it would restart and resume at joke #5 )

thanks

Comment: Yes, but more context to your problem would provide better and more useful answers, instead of a bunch of guess and noise which just clutter the issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer  -  thank you, I added in some more

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "and it will be in same context".

Comment: @KenGeis - thanks,  what I mean is that my program will have a sequence of states it goes through - say, 10 of them. And so , if we shutdown on the beginning step 7 (i.e before step 7 completes), then it should be restarted and resume on step 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can run as many seperate JRE processes as you like. The only limitation is the finite resources of the machine. Two (or more) processes cannot open and listen on the same socket on the same IP (for example).

Comment: To add, the total heap size used by all the separate processes couldn't exceed your machine's memory.

Comment: @ares That's not correct. We've had virtual memory since about 1957.

Comment: Ports are a terrible example for exclusive resource use. There's SO_REUSEADDR (for multicast) and SO_REUSEPORT (for unicast).

Comment: @EJP - how does the virtual memory affect this ?

Comment: @the8472  - Can you elaborate a little bit about that? Why are ports such a bad idea?

Comment: They're just a bad example because they can in fact be opened by more than one process. If you want to know more you should read the docs on the socket options i mentioned (google them).

Comment: @Coffee It means you can overcommit physical memory.

Comment: @the8472 You have that back to front. SO_REUSEADDR is for unicast; SO_REUSEPORT is for multicast.

Comment: @EJP, I don't think so. SO_REUSEADDR is sufficient for share multicast sockets, SO_REUSEPORT is necessary to share listen sockets.